# selenium c# : i can not use Sendkey(Keys.control+"v") in headless mode

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm having issues with Selenium WebDriver in C# when trying to use SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v") in headless mode. Interestingly, the same code works fine when not in headless mode. It seems that I can only use SendKeys in Google Chrome versions 110-111.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var element_send = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='chatroomEditor-module__editor_area__1UsgR']/textarea-ex"));
element_send.Click();
Clipboard_.SetText(msg[random_msg]);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
element_send.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "v");
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
element_send.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

I've also tried using JavaScriptExecutor, but without success:

```
var element_send = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='chatroomEditor-module__editor_area__1UsgR']/textarea-ex"));                                                   js.ExecuteScript($"arguments[0].value='{msg[random_msg]}';", element_send);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
element_send.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue, or does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

i want to use sendkey in headless mode

Comment: If you are encountering an error, please [edit] your question to include the error message and stack trace. If you are not encountering an error, please describe the behavior you are observing.